# Exchange Web Services FindItem (by body search criteria) not finding email with larger body

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a routine (pretty standard) from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633693(v=exchg.80).aspx which I use to return a list of emails that contain a specific content ("homecoming") in the body of the email.

```
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Body, "homecoming"));
```

The issue is that I have an email that is about 109K in size and this email is not being returned in the results.

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);
```

I have moved the "homecoming" text to an earlier portion of the email body and it is then returned as expected.  It appears to only be searching the first x bytes of the email body.  Is there anyway to ensure that the entire email body is search regardless of size?

UPDATE:
This may not be a size issue, just tested on a larger email and email was found.  But on the offending email as soon as I make the email smaller it works, add a single extra character to make it large and it doesn't find it.

UPDATE:
Here is a sample email that suffers from the problem.  I am searching for FindText1 thru FindText10.  It works from FindText1 thru FindText7 but fails from FindText8 onwards.  This is a plain text email.

```
FindText1
Example of a one with a DIS ref caught up in other code.

From: QQQ O'QQQQQQ [mailto:QQQ@QQQQQQQQ.QQQ.QQ] 
Sent: Wednesday, 27 March 2013 2:50 PM
To: QQQQQ QQQQQQ
Subject: Re: FW: FW: QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ - Website Proposal DS:02303779

Hi QQQQQ,
We don't have a logo per se....I do have a letter head type thing that is very dodgy and just throw all the individual brand logos together. I will attach here. Maybe you guys could design something similar but a bit more nicer/advanced?
In regards to the advert banners, we soon will have our april marketing offers ( all are ending 30/3 so no point at moment) and I could send them to you to play with?
I have a great wall image that I will also attach here.
Thanks,
QQQ
On 26/03/2013 2:57 PM, QQQQQ QQQQQQ wrote:
Hello QQQ
FindText2
We have the paperwork from you (via QQQQQ QQQQQ) …..Thank You.

I have scheduled in the work and will keep in touch with progress. One thing. Do you have a LOGO for the QQQQQQQQ Group? Maybe you have some artwork on how you wish this title to be used? If not we will just use a text based title.

Also, we are allowing for rotating banners on each site. Do you have an example of the advert banners that we could use in design?

Happy to discuss any issues.

Regards

QQQQQ QQQQQQ
Relationship Manager - Online Service

FindText3
M 
QQQQ QQQ QQQ
P 
QQQQ QQ QQ QQ
F 
QQQQ QQ QQ QQ

Stay Up-To-Date With Our News Blog

www.dealersolutions.com.au

-----Original Message-----
From: QQQQQ QQQQQQ 
Sent: Wednesday, 20 March 2013 2:56 PM
To: 'QQQ QQQQQQQQQ'
Cc: QQQQQ QQQQQ
Subject: RE: FW: QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ - Website Proposal DS:02303779

Hello QQQ
FindText4
Great News

QQQQQ QQQQQ from our Sydney office will contact you shortly to arrange the sign up and we can get going. We will commence with the Corporate Landing page and stage it from there. Is this what you have in mind? 

Thanks for your confidence in going with us and I look forward to working with you.

Best Regards
QQQQQ

-----Original Message-----
From: QQQ O'QQQQQQQ [mailto:QQQQ@QQQQQQQQ.QQQ.QQ] 
Sent: Wednesday, 20 March 2013 10:41 AM
To: QQQQQ QQQQQQ
Subject: Re: FW: QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ - Website Proposal DS:02303779

Hi QQQQQ,
Yes, sounds like a plan to us.
Havent had a go ahead for skoda site as yet but ready to move forward with landing page asap.
Thanks,
QQQ
FindText5 
On 8/03/2013 11:26 AM, QQQQQ QQQQQQ wrote:
> Hello QQQ
> 
> Just a follow up to see if you have had a chance to look through our proposal provided last Wednesday and to see if you have any questions.  I do hope we can assist.
> 
> I would like to arrange a telephone hook to discuss in more detail what you want with our James Bolden, the web person who will be looking after this for you. Just let us know a convenient time and I will call so we can discuss any issues.
> 
> I await your advice.
> 
> Regards
> QQQQQ
> 
> -----Original Message-----
> From: QQQQQ QQQQQQ
> Sent: Wednesday, 6 March 2013 4:06 PM
> To: 'QQQ QQQQQQQQQ'
> Subject: QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ - Website Proposal DS:02303779
> 
> Hello QQQ
> 
> Thank you for your patience on this.
> FindText6
> Please find attached our proposal for the new QQQQQQQQ Group website and for updating the Ford website.
> 
> We are understanding of your requirements and feel we have priced the sites to achieve what you are wanting.
> 
> I will call to discuss the elements in the proposal.
> 
> Best Regards
> QQQQQ
> 
> -----Original Message-----
> From: QQQ O'QQQQQQQ [mailto:QQQQ@QQQQQQQQ.QQQ.QQ]
> Sent: Thursday, 21 February 2013 12:59 PM
> To: QQQQQ QQQQQQ
> Subject: QQQ
> 
> Hi QQQQQ,
> I spoke briefly with the guys about the website yesterday and told them to look at mike blewitts landing page.
> They came back to me and told me to show you the apple/ipad website..
> http://www.apple.com/. They want the site to be as simple and clean as this.
FindText7
> So basically QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ across the top. One main image (that can change/rotate throuh specials if possible?) and then 5 boxes below that with each brands logo and name and one for QQQ used cars. Phone numbers underneath each box and thats about it. Just crisp, clean and easy. I think they want to leave out the quick search until they reach one of the other sites. I have a rough drawing I could probably fax or scan and email if this would be helpful..
> Hope this makes sense.
> Thanks,
> QQQ
> FindText8
> --
> QQQ QQQQQQQQQ
> 
> QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ
> QQQ QQQQ Q QQQQQQQQ QQQ
> QQQQQ QQQ QQQQ
> Ph: QQ QQQQ QQQQ
> Fax: QQ QQQQ QQQQ
> 
> 

DISREF:24333;9;0;0;1:DISREF
 FindText9
--
QQQ QQQQQQQQQ

QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ
QQQ QQQQ Q QQQQQQQQ QQQ
QQQQQ QQQ QQQQ
Ph: QQ QQQQ QQQQ
Fax: QQ QQQQ QQQQ



-- 
QQQ QQQQQQQQQ

QQQQQQQQ QQQQQ QQQQQ
QQQ QQQQ Q QQQQQQQQ QQQ
QQQQQ QQQ QQQQ
Ph: QQ QQQQ QQQQ
Fax: QQ QQQQ QQQQ

FindText10


<<<
```

Comment: What version of Excahnge server?

Comment: Play with the various possibilities of the ContainmentMode attribute as described in the section "Search expressions" in David Sterling book "Inside Microsoft Exchange server 2007 web services" (http://books.google.nl/books?id=9I0g-GAKm6YC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: "SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(PropertyDefinitionBase, String, ContainmentMode, ComparisonMode)" as defined e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.searchfilter.containssubstring_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Comment: We use Microsoft Exchange online, which according to this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/determine-the-version-of-microsoft-exchange-server-my-account-connects-to-HA010355044.aspx reports that we are running against - Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 SP2.

Comment: I have tried all combinations of the ContainmentMode and ComparisonMode against, EmailMessageSchema.Body.

I am also experiencing more emails suffering from the same problem.

The only thing I can raise at this stage, they appear to be from a specific user.  But not all of their emails.

Comment: I am interrogating the Sent Items folder, I have reason to believe that the user may have deleted the email and the restored it.  Could this be causing an issue?

Comment: I'm out of suggestions, other than maybe trying these forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopmentlegacy/threads and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/threads

Comment: I have reworked my process to handle this differently to ensure a working solution, but it still leaves this unresolved.  I feel like this is an EWS API 2.0 bug.  Any ideas on the best place to report it?